# If user not entered all data in input, then dialog modal will not be displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<form id="form_save_account" action="." method="post">
   <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="618376f08ab0b6f255442d9519ec656a" /></div>
   <div class="container" />
   <div class="row" />
   <div class="span5" />

<div class="id_account_owner-control-group control-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="id_account_owner"> account owner </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input id="id_account_owner" type="text" name="account_owner" maxlength="250" />
      </div>
   </div>

<div class="id_account_number-control-group control-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="id_account_number"> account number </label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input id="id_account_number" type="text" name="account_number" maxlength="34" />
      </div>
   </div>

<div class="span1 offset10">
      <a type="submit" name"save-continue-to-review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog" href="" class="btn primary btn-primary" title="Go">Go
      </a>
   </div>
</form


<script>

...

</script>
```

How to create something like this:

If user do not type all the data in inputs that dialog modal from this:

```
  <a type="submit" name"save-continue-to-review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog" href="" class="btn primary btn-primary" title="Go">Go
  </a>
```

will not be displayed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have client side validation for all input fields on submit.
Add **onclick** event on submit. For ex:

```
<a type="submit" onclick="javascript:yourFunctionName();" name"save-continue-to-review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog" href="" class="btn primary btn-primary" title="Go">Go
```

and in JS file just define the function as :

```
function yourFunctionName(){
    var account_owner = document.getElementById(id_account_owner).value;
    var account_no    = document.getElementById(id_account_number).value;
    if(account_no == '' || account_owner == ''){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) for more info.

I think it will help you.

Comment: Than you, but I don't know how to check "is ALL input typed"

Comment: Angelina: I have updated my code. Just check it, may it will help you.

Comment: And How to create if this: if(account_no == '' || account_owner == ''){
        return false;
    } is false then delete this: data-toggle="modal" from my a type="submit" or change to a different value?